# Identify the index of each row where items get wrapped in Wrap panel & also identify possible no of items available in each row

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF for Wrap panel I want to know the index of each row where items get wrapped. I also want to know the possible number of items available in each row in wrap panel based on width dynamically.

Is there any mechanism to get idea about this?

Regards

Vipul

Comment: May I ask what you're trying to achieve? Perhaps there's a simpler route. As for the possible number of items, you can calculate that in your viewmodel / code-behind by using the width of your item and the actual width of the container.

Comment: Actually I have a list view. I use Wrap panel within list view to show items. It works perfectly fine. Now I want something like when I click on item then its details should be show in new line below the row in which that item (on which we clicked) exist. I do not want to use Gridview because here in single row there are more than one items. So I am searching like is there any approach to identify the number of items available in each row.

Comment: @vipullangalia based on your previous content i would use a datagrid, with rowdetails enabled

Comment: But in my case in one row multiple items can come each item will represent one item in list. In dataGrid one row shows one item in list. So that will not work.